# Rails redirect_to is redirecting from https (correct) to http (incorrect)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, nginx, https, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have a `before_action` requiring the user to be logged in, like so:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :require_login

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:alert] = "You must be logged in to access this section."
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    # more logic
  end
end
```

When I visit `example.com` without being logged in, I get redirected to `example.com/login` as expected. However, I see this error in the console:

```
The page at 'https://example.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed
insecure content from 'http://example.com/login': this content should also
be loaded over HTTPS.
```

The network tab appears to indicate that my `redirect_to` is pointing me to `HTTP` and not `HTTPS`. When it hits the HTTP, it then automatically redirects to `HTTPS`.

```
Request URL:http://example.com/login
Request Method:GET
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently

# In the response headers:
Location:https://example.com/login
```

Is there a way to tell the `redirect_to` that it should use `HHTPS` instead of `HTTP`, or is this an nginx config? I thought that using `login_path` as opposed to `login_url` would fix the issue since it should be relative to the base, but that didn't seem to work.

---

Update:

I thought about using `force_ssl` as well but was worried that I was taking a hammer to a push pin. Feel free to correct me if I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`#force_ssl`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html#method-i-force_ssl):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  force_ssl # use HTTPS for all actions

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :require_login

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:alert] = "You must be logged in to access this section."
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

  def logged_in?
    # more logic
  end
end
```

Comment: Will `force_ssl` affect all traffic? I thought about that solution as well but was worried that I was taking a hammer to a push pin.

Comment: It will affect everything that is under `ApplicationController`, so propably all your controllers. You should add it in the controller you want to though, I guess that would be the controller you 've defined the `login` action in.

Answer (score 6):

In your `application.rb` (or `environment.rb`), you could set

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

This would make Rails use a secure end-point always.